# MongoDb - change entry by identifier?

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to modify Mongo document entry by id?
in the example below I want to change checked property to true where identifier is priner.settings.id4

```java
{
    "identifier": "priner.settings.id4",
    "Question caption": "Check ink flow",
    "checked": "false"
}
```

kinda like in SQL

```
 update table set checked = true where identifier = 'priner.settings.id4'
```

the document itself is huge so I am trying to avoid  appending the entire path to the setting like

```
InspectionContent-> inkLevels -> PrinterInspection -> questions
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

sample document:

```java
{
    "InspectionContent": {
        "InkLevels": {
            "PrinterInspection": {
                "questions": [

                    {
                        "identifier": "priner.settings.id1",
                        "Question caption": "Check link level",
                        "checked": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "priner.settings.id2",
                        "Question caption": "Check ink cond",
                        "checked": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "priner.settings.id3",
                        "Question caption": "Check ink color",
                        "checked": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "identifier": "priner.settings.id4",
                        "Question caption": "Check ink flow",
                        "checked": "false"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db-collection-update) not do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

you need [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) to update nested array elements.

```java
db.collection.update(
    {},
    {
        $set: { "InspectionContent.InkLevels.PrinterInspection.questions.$[x].checked": "true" }
    },
    {
        multi: true,
        arrayFilters: [
            { "x.identifier": { $eq: "priner.settings.id4" } }
        ]
    }
)
```